# How to fix Parsing image id from firebase to RecycleView java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

Tags: java, android

I'm binding an image to `RecycleView` with Drawable `id` like `R.drawable.potatoes` from a firebase database. It throws an exception. Images stored in res Drawable directory. Thank you.

I've tried following formates:

```
[Picasso.with(context).load(listVegetables.get(position).getImage()); 
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(listVegetables.get(position).getImage()));
         holder.image.setBackgroundResource(Integer.parseInt(listVegetables.get(position).getImage()));
         holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(listVegetables.get(position).getImage()));][1]
```

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

         holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(listVegetables.get(position).getImage()));
         holder.vegetableName.setText(listVegetables.get(position).getName());
         holder.price.setText(listVegetables.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.qunType.setText(listVegetables.get(position).getQunType());
    }
```

I expect Image display on recycleview.

Comment: what getImage() returns?

Comment: what do you mean by image id?

Comment: can you tell what getImage() returns?

Comment: string object returns

Comment: Sir, listVegetables.get(position).getImage() this return : R.drawable.potatoes.